# Server-side response will not show in PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile app

Tags: forms, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, cross-domain

I have a fairly simple jQuery mobile app, which works fine as a web app (tested in browsers on desktops/smartphones) but when porting it to android using phonegap, I have one major issue. It occurs both on a real phone and in an AVD.

there's a form in the app, like:

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="dialog" id="a-form">
    <div data-role="content">
        <h3>...</h3>
        <form action="http://a-live-site.com/a-form.php" method="post">
            ...
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its response content loads perfectly in the browser (the `action` is a relative link there), but within phonegap I just get a white screen and the hardware back button exits the app instead of the usual step back in history. The puzzling thing is that the request actually gets through. The server side code triggers an email, so I know the server is getting the request. I have added the appropriate `<access />` rules in the `phonegap.xml` file, but I'm not sure that's enough.

EDIT: the form is in static content so, in phonegap, it's loaded by `file://` and shouldn't have cross-domain issues.

Comment: but is your server actually returning anything to display after the form data has been handled? I'd suggest checking out with Fiddler...

Comment: It was definitely serving a response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to `data-role="dialog"` in the result. Using `page` fixed it. It only broke in phonegap and phonegap's logs made it look like it was something else. A real PITA.